# VB.net console application: capturing screen output in a file

Tags: vb.net, logging, command-line

In my vb.net command line script, I have written a few functions. I want to direct the output of these functions, both errors and general logs, into a log file.
I was hoping to make my log file declaration as global, so that I don't have to open and close my log file in every function. (I don't want to declare it every where).

Looking for an efficient way of achieving this.

Comment: What does _O/P_ mean?

Comment: There's no such thing as a VB.NET commandline script.  Do you actually mean that you have a Console application written in VB.NET or do you mean that you have a VB.NET application that is opening a console window and sending commands to it or do you mean something else?